# Repeatedly apply the same command to a lot of variables in R

Tags: r

I want to repeatedly do the same thing using a lot of variables. I´m new in R and I don't know how to do it.

The thing I want to do is create a variable in another data frame from a set of 27 variables i.e:

```
elecc$PAN <- rowsum(presidencia$PAN, presidencia$llave, 
                              reorder = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
elecc$PRI <- rowsum(presidencia$PRI, presidencia$llave, 
                    reorder = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
```

What command in R will do this?

Comment: Just do `elecc[c("PAN", "PRI")] <- rowsum(presidencia[c("PAN", "PRI")], presidencia$llave, reorder = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)]`

Comment: IT doesn't work :(

Comment: You haven't showed any reproducible example.  It does work based on an example I tried `rowsum(iris[1:4], iris$Species, reorder = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)`

Comment: Sorry. IT TOTALLY WORKED!!! there were a plus ] in your code the first time and i didn´t realized it.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:
`elecc[c("PAN", "PRI")] <- rowsum(presidencia[c("PAN", "PRI")], presidencia$llave, reorder = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)]`

(credit to comment from user [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun))